# Throws "server error 429" - run time error

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I wanted to import the csv file into sharepoint list, but its throwing 429 error for every 10 min.
i have tried the below code. please help to resolve. Thanks in advance.

```
            ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, sec_pass);

            ctx.ExecutingWebRequest += delegate (object sender, WebRequestEventArgs e)
            {
                e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.UserAgent = "NONISV|Den|Migration/1.0";
            };

            ctx.RequestTimeout = -1;

            ctx.Load(ctx.Web);
            ctx.Load(ctx.Web.Webs);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: You are exceeding the limits set by your specific sharepoint site admin and hence you are getting this 'HTTP 429 too many requests' error.

Comment: when i run 50k documents it rarely throws an error not like every 10 min. but now i'm facing this for every 10 min even if i have only 500 documents it stops

Comment: these type of threshold limits are set in the format "per X minutes window only allow Y calls"...so, you might not have faced if you did uploads over a longer period of time.

Comment: Read about SharepointOnline [throttling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online#what-is-throttling)